# buildPaths in app.json Sencha Touch 2.1 seems to be removed

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

In my Sencha 2.0 App I had this in the app.json to defined where it should put the "compiled" javascript, but in Sencha 2.1 example apps its removed. It isnt respected after I updated to Sencha 2.1, anyone ones what happend to this?

```
/**
 * Default paths to build this application to for each environment
 */
"buildPaths": {
    "testing": "../../../../parentapp/build/testing",
    "production": "../../../../parentapp/build/production",
    "package": "../../../../parentapp/build/package",
    "native": "../../../../parentapp/build/native"
},
```

Comment: I'm using Sencha Touch 2.1 and my app.json does have a `"buildPaths"` parameter (which is set similar to yours) and building works as expected. I think you may have something else going on in your build making it not work. Are you getting error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sencha Touch 2.1 and Sencha Cmd 3.1 no longer use app.json's [buildPaths](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247180-Sencha-Cmd-v3.0.0.190-does-not-use-app.json-buildpath-settings).

These are now defined (well, scattered) in a sequence of build.xml, build-impl.xml, and sencha.cfg files.

Display hidden directories/file and navigate to directory for your app. In this folder you will find a hidden folder named ".sencha". Within this folder you will find a folder "app" as well as "workspace" possibly (workspace is not a default creation). Inside the app folder is sencha.cfg where you can define the default build path for your application.

This option will place your builds in a folder "build" above your app folder:

```
app.build.dir=${app.dir}/../build
```

Using Sencha Cmd you can then type the following line, with the optional suffix defining type of build (defaults to production).

```
sencha app build (testing|production|package|native)
```

Package builds use a file called packager.json for build details.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I downgraded again after all problems with upgrade to Sencha 2.1, but soon time to try again.

Comment: Sencha 2.2 released today. Does away with singular reliance on webkit, now supporting IE10 as well as far improved/included support for other devices - esp Blackberry and Android. Also includes "themes" - something that has been available to Ext4.2 but not Touch, until now. The major hiccup from 2.0 to 2.1 was dynamic height rendering of lists. I know lists got another major overhaul, but yet to test whether this issue was fixed.

Comment: Cool, thanks, will try again to update to Sencha 2.2, last time I had to give up and downgrade to 2.0